# how to set initial value for JTextFiled that can't be deleted

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

i know how to put an initial value for `JTextFiled`, but how to set the property of the value to be fixed?

This is the normal way for the value

```
JTextFiled is = new JTextFiled("00:00:00");
```

Sure, the output will be a text field with value 00:00:00, but the user can delete that. How can I stop that from happening? 
The value of the field is 00:00:00, if the user tries to delete the value Java will stop him if he tried to edit the value. The only way is by using numbers from the keyboard.

Comment: Try `setEnabled(false)`. Please have a look at [Component#setEnabled()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setEnabled%28boolean%29)

Comment: Could also do something fun like set an action listener to restore its old value, but that is unnecessary, and will make your users angry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1 - Use a `JFormattedTextField` with a `SimpleDateFormat`:**

```
JFormattedTextField textField = new JFormattedTextField(new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss:SSS"));
textField.setText("00:00:00:000");
```

- You can replace the format string according to your needs by looking at the [SimpleDateFormat API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).
- This pattern works as long as the movie is not longer than 24 hours.
- This way the user can delete the string, but once he leaves the text field the string will return to what it was before. Only strings of the specified format will actually be accepted as the value.

**Option 2 - Use a `JFormattedTextField` with a `MaskFormatter`:**

```
MaskFormatter mask = null;
try {
    mask = new MaskFormatter("##:##:##:###");
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
mask.setValidCharacters("0123456789");
mask.setPlaceholderCharacter('0');
JFormattedTextField textField2 = new JFormattedTextField(mask);
textField2.setText("00:00:00:000");
```

- You can replace the format string according to your needs by looking at the [MaskFormatter API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/MaskFormatter.html).
- This pattern works as long as the movie is not longer than 99 hours, but minutes and seconds count can exceed 59 (e.g. you can have 01:76:98:123 read: 1 hour 76 minutes 98 seconds 123 milliseconds).
- This way the user can only type digits (specified by "0123456789") and deleting any of the numbers will replace them with 0 (specified by '0').

Comment: both of the way are not right the filed are editable but with knowing value so the user can't change the right value (int value 00:00:00) to string value by removing the number in the text filed and adding text

Comment: it is like it have form

Comment: Oh wait, there's a small chance I understand what you want. You want the user to change the value but it needs to remain of the form ##:##:##, as if the user inputs hour:minute:second?

Comment: StackOverflow is pushing my reading comprehensions skills to the limit. I'll edit the answer with what you wanted.

Comment: this is some how right answer but not what i want my idea was to Disable backspace function in my keyboard and enable editing using numbers keys in my keyboard only

Comment: how to represent this  pattern form movie 00:01:09,069

Comment: Why backspace? The user can remove the text with the delete key, or by selecting it with the mouse, right clicking and choosing cut or delete. Did you account for those?

Comment: Do you want to represent "hours:minutes:seconds,milliseconds"? Are those the last 3 digits?

Comment: yes i added comment under my answer but still there is issue of what is the pattern of movie timing 00:01:09,069 and how to stop delete and how to write over the number not deleting it if you like to see example you can look for aegisub application

Comment: I edited the answer. As I said, you can't delete it, the input has to be of the for specified by pattern. You will have to explain better and not send us to another program.

Comment: sorry right hours:minutes:seconds,milliseconds i think kk:mm:ss:SSS

Comment: Read the link in my answer for formatting the string. kk starts from 1, you want to start from 0.

Comment: ok that is right but is there a way to set the value of the filed to 00:00:00:00 when the application start and also is there a way to stop hem from deleting the data and force hem to change only by clicking on the the number button on the keyboard

Answer (score 0):

this is how to disable the backspace function

```
textField.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("BACK_SPACE"), "none");
```

Comment: but i can't get what is the none for